# Help to delimit and read specific contents of incoming HTTP string

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, string, serial-data

I am sending strings to an Esp8266 via web browser.

The below code returns the following in serial monitor if I send in browser:

Send from browser to esp8266 - http://192.168.1.220/s1s2s3s4s5d1
Receive in Arduino Serial monitor - GET /s1s2s3s4s5d2 HTTP/1.1

How do i read only the contents s1s2s3s4s5d1  ? This content can vary in length, numbers could be double digits but alphabets will remain in between.

Please note I am still a novice.

```cpp
// Read the first line of the request
String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
Serial.println(request);
client.flush();
```

Comment: google `arduino parsing strings`

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to implement some methods unsuccessfully. i simply do not have the experience especially since the content required varies in length. i was hoping to get an example if possible.

Comment: do you have any control over the URL format ....maybe you need to use something like http://192.168.1.220?s=1&s2=4&s3=8&d=1&abcd=1234

Comment: will this method retain the letters or does it strip to numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I have this

```
if (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available() && client.find(' ')) { // GET /fn HTTP/1.1
    char fn[20];
    int l = client.readBytesUntil(' ', fn, sizeof(fn));
    fn[l] = 0;
    while (client.read() != -1);
    Serial.println(fn);
    client.stop(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will apply solution and revert.

Comment: @s-b, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
int first_space = request.indexOf(' '); // location of the first space
int second_space = request.indexOf(' ', first_space); // the next space after first

String query_arg = request.substring(first_space,second_space);
```